# javascript - how to obtain span text values within a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to implement a click event listener for a drop-down menu. So far I'm not having much luck trying to drill down into the values within it. Here is the html I'm working with:

```
<div class="dropdown" data-id="123">
    <div class="arrow">▼</div>
        <span class="value">uk</span>
            <div class="select" tabindex="0" style="display: none; width: 134px;">
                <span data-id="781" class="selected">uk</span>
                <span data-id="782" class>usa</span>
                <span data-id="783">china</span>
                <span data-id="784">africa</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

If I click on the option 'africa' within the drop-down I'd like an alert to display 'africa'. So far I have this, but would appreciate more opinions on how I can achieve this:

```
jQuery('dropdown select').on('mousedown',function(){ alert(jQuery(this).text()); })
```

Thank you.

Comment: Try this `jQuery('.dropdown .select').on('mousedown',function(){ alert(jQuery(this).text()); })`. Note `.` before class in `JQuery(...`

Comment: Why aren't you using `select` element with `change` event?

Comment: Shouldn't `jQuery('dropdown select')` be `jQuery('.dropdown select')`? You're missing `.` before `dropdown`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put `click` event on `$(".select span")`

```js
$(".select span").on("click",function(){
  alert($(this).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown" data-id="123">
    <div class="arrow">▼</div>
        <span class="value">uk</span>
            <div class="select">
                <span data-id="781" class="selected">uk</span>
                <span data-id="782" class>usa</span>
                <span data-id="783">china</span>
                <span data-id="784">africa</span>
            </div>
</div>
```

You forgot to add dot `.` before class here, also need to add span to track each span

```
jQuery('.dropdown .select span').on('mousedown',function(){ alert(jQuery(this).text()); })
```